# How to make VS Code compound debugger run by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have the following `.vscode/launch.json` config:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Next: Chrome",
      "url": "localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Next: Node",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      "port": 9229,
      "env": {
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect"
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Next: Full",
      "configurations": ["Next: Node", "Next: Chrome"]
    }
  ]
}
```

By starting debugger with <kbd>F5</kbd>, I want it to run the `Next: Full` command. But instead it runs `Next: Chrome`, so it may seem like something's not working, but you have to change it manually and re-run:

[image: vscode dubugger options]

Then it will work. But is it possible to set it as default within the config?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by adding additional helpful entry to `configurations` first in the list, with the same name (type and request are also necessary):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "Next: Full",
      "request": "launch"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Next: Chrome",
      "url": "localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Next: Node",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      "port": 9229,
      "env": {
        "NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect"
      }
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Next: Full",
      "configurations": ["Next: Node", "Next: Chrome"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which turns out to be working as an alias:

[image]